# how to select week days range from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have query like

```
SELECT uq.timespan, COALESCE(tsq.TotalClicks, 0) as Clicks FROM (
SELECT '22-28 days' as timespan
union SELECT '15-21 days'
union SELECT '8-14 days'
union SELECT 'up to 7 days'
)uq LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days'
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days'
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
        AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '8-14 days'
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN 'up to 7 days'
           END Weeksubmitdate, 
           count(id) TotalClicks
FROM $survey
WHERE submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY Weeksubmitdate
)tsq ON uq.timespan = tsq.Weeksubmitdate
```

its output is like

```
22-28 days  4
15-21 days  1
8-14 days   1
up to 7 days    11
```

now i want to change output with week days 
like

```
mon-sun     2
mon-sun     0
mon-sun     7
mon-sun     5
```

suppose now i am on thursday, it should count in this week mon-sun.

Comment: Can you give an example of the records and the output it should give?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. here i want to calculate like 22 oct - 28 oct, 29 oct - 4 nov, 5  nov - 11 nov , 11 nov - 18 nov